# Stop infinitive scroll on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have set infinitive scrolling on table and it's working fine

```
<tbody infinite-scroll-disabled="myModule.isScrollingDisabled()" infinite-scroll="myModule.nextPage()" infinate-scroll-immediate-check="false" infinite-scroll-distance="3">
```

But the problem comes when i try to stop it on a click event on checkbox. So as You can see i have method `isScrollingDisabled`.

```
myModule.prototype.isScrollingDisabled = function() {
    return this.disabledScroll;
};
```

And i have a setter that fires each time i click on checkbox and sets `disabledScroll` flag correctly.

```
myModule.prototype.toggleScrollingDisabled = function(status) {
    this.disabledScroll = status;
};
```

It gets called on refreshing the page and the problem is that `isScrollingDisabled` is never called again. Is there a way that i can trigger it and get `disabledScroll` state and then disable or enable scrolling.

I can get value of attribute `infinite-scroll-disabled` to change to false or true with some basic js, but it doesn't affect scrolling, angular stops watching it, parsing is done and event is never triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add [`$scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) and then angular is re-rendering page and everything works as intended.